# Need help in CSS floats, clears and positing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put these two divs side by side but unsuccessful. guide me how can i make these two divs align side by side. i knew that this can be done by clear:both but couldn't do it. my attempt is:

http://jsfiddle.net/rizwan1969/hkrryt8w/

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    width:950px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
    #messgae{
    width:650px;
    float:left;


    }
    #sidebar-one{

    width:260px;
    float:left
    }
```

Plz refer me a fiddle to learn this. Thanks

Comment: Check your spelling.

Comment: you have a speeling msitake in your CSS..change it to `#message`

Comment: check Your spelling you have a spelling mistake in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you have a spelling mistake in your CSS..change `#messgae` to `#message`

Change your CSS as follows

```
#wrapper{
    width:950px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
    #message{
    width:650px;
    float:left;


    }
    #sidebar-one{

    width:260px;
    float:left
    }
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/hkrryt8w/1/)

Answer (score 0):

css

```
#wrapper{   width:950px;    margin:0 auto; }
#message{   width:650px;    float:left; }
#sidebar-one{   width:260px;    float:left }
```

html

```
<body>    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="message"> This is messgae div</div>
    <div id="sidebar-one"> This is Sidebar One</div>    </div> </body>
```